# How to use pivot_longer on 1x3 dataframe

Tags: r

How do you transform the following tibble, so that x,y,z can be used as primary key "group" with the values as "val"?

```
tbl1 <- tibble (x = 1, y = 2, z = 3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `pivot_longer` with `everything()` for `cols` to select all the columns

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(tbl1, everything(), names_to = "group", values_to = "val")
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  group   val
#  <chr> <dbl>
#1 x         1
#2 y         2
#3 z         3
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
stack(tbl1)
```

#### data

```
tbl1 <- tibble(x = 1, y = 2, z = 3)
```